# KCFinder upload working, but CKEditor not display images

Tags: ckeditor, kcfinder

When I upload some image in CKeditor, it works fine and the image is via KCFinder uploaded. But that's all.. in popout is not any preview of image. Is on server, but CKEditor don't get path. Where is a problem?

**CKeditor**

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'http://zssever.damidev.com/admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
```

Comment: If its all on the same server try giving relative path (../xyz/upload) or absolute path (/var/www/my-project/xyz/upload/)

Comment: I have same problem, did you solved it?

Comment: I also have the same problem, but no solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212432/ckeditor-and-kcfinder-image-preview-on-godaddy

Comment: any solution to this?