# CKEditor and KCfinder image preview on GoDaddy

Tags: php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I am having a problem with preview of image through KCFinder on CKEditor on GoDaddy hosting.

When I select the image from KCFinder the preview is loaded correctly on my local machine, but when I check on GoDaddy it is not showing correctly. Difference can be seen from below images.

I have configured the file browser in CKEditor as shown in below snippet.

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/browse.php?type=media';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/upload.php?type=media';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../admin/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
```

And the KCFinder session is as follows

```
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadURL'] = "../upload";
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadDir'] = "../upload";
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false;
```

Image preview in my localhost.

[image: Image on local machine]

Image preview on GoDaddy hosting

[image]

The main problem I am unable to get the "upload/" directory in URL. You can see the difference in above images.

Can anyone help, how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem on 1&1, but not in Gigas. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No I didn't found solution of it, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the absolute path for the uploadURL and it worked!

Comment: this can go in comment

Comment: how to use absolute path in kc finder help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `conf` folder inside "`kcfinder`", then open `upload.htaccess` file and remove whole text from this (upload.htaccess) file. Finally save it.

And also delete `.htaccess` file from `upload` folder inside `kcfinder` folder.

I hope it's better.

Answer (score 0):

you should change  '_check4htaccess' => true, line in config.php '_check4htaccess' => false, and delete .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, Googling for solution and I found this site. But finally I solve the problem and let me share here.

Just put the x image in the text area. By using menu 'source', check the image url. See what is the problem. If you find something like /plugins/ckeditor/file-manager/yourweb.com/...., it means that you are not put http:// in your upload dir. It should be like this :

```
'disabled' => false,
'uploadURL' => "https://mywebsite.com/img/upload/",
'uploadDir' => "/home/XXXXXXX/public_html/img/upload/", 
'theme' => "default",
```

Try to close the browser and restart again after changing that code. It works in goDaddy hosting. And I use sub domain to access the image by using https://img.mywebsite.com/upload/ ....the image.